# Ability to view responses sent to Employers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I'd like to be able to see the messages I sent as responses to Employers after the fact, not just the *not interested*, *interested* status.

Comment: Also, is this your SO account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/20774/james-mcmahon  If so, we can merge the account you used to ask this question with your other Meta account.

Comment: @Jarrod, it is, somehow my SO, SF and SU accounts got linked to this account http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/20774/nemo. I would appreciate the merge and would prefer the name James McMahon on all accounts. Thanks.

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon, hey just commenting to give you a heads up, my accounts are still not merged. I screwed up the @ in the last comment so I don't think the system gave you a notification.

Comment: All done - sorry for the delay!

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon, awesome! Thank you for taking time out of your schedule to do that for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your optional responses to an employer's message are now visible when viewing an individual message.

Comment: Thank you, I am not seeing them however. Do I have to click something on the employer message?

Comment: This is now in production - we were tweaking some build scripts that delayed its inception; sorry!

Comment: I can see it now. Thanks again.